# Appending information to existing description in Jira Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-jira

I am trying to use jira-python for creating and updating existing issues. I wanted to know whether we can append information to existing description. I tried to use issue.update, but it overwrites existing description. Please let me know whether this is possible using Jira-Python.

For Eg:

**Current Description**

Description 1

**Description after updating**

Description 1
Description 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below approach.

1. Get the existing description
2. Add the new description
3. Then use issue.update

> ```
> Description = issue.fields.description
>
> Description = Description + " " + "Description 2"
>
> issue.update(description=Description)
> ```